# How to make line chart using dynamic data

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

we want to create line chart using dynamic data this is my data

```
      [["2014-12-31",44656252,"Total All Banks"],["2013-12-31",41444774,"Total All Banks"],["2014-12-31",42615758,"Total Domestic Banks"],["2013-12-31",39217025,"Total Domestic Banks"],["2014-12-31",50181,"B2B Bank"],["2013-12-31",30550,"B2B Bank"],["2014-12-31",5235860,"Bank of Montreal"],["2013-12-31",5377685,"Bank of Montreal"],["2014-12-31",9300153,"The Bank of Nova Scotia"],["2013-12-31",8460296,"The Bank of Nova Scotia"]]
```

for this i tried :

```
          arradata="[["2014-12-31",44656252,"Total All Banks"],["2013-12-31",41444774,"Total All Banks"],["2014-12-31",42615758,"Total Domestic Banks"],["2013-12-31",39217025,"Total Domestic Banks"],["2014-12-31",50181,"B2B Bank"],["2013-12-31",30550,"B2B Bank"],["2014-12-31",5235860,"Bank of Montreal"],["2013-12-31",5377685,"Bank of Montreal"],["2014-12-31",9300153,"The Bank of Nova Scotia"],["2013-12-31",8460296,"The Bank of Nova Scotia"]]";
            dataTable.addColumn('string','Transaction date');
            dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Net income before income tax');
            for(var i=0; i<=names.length-1;i++){
            var transvalue="'"+names[i]+"'";
            console.log(transvalue);
            dataTable.addColumn('string', transvalue);
            }// dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Net Income before extraordinaryitems');
            //console.log(arrayvalue);
            //dataTable.addRows(JSON.parse(arraydata));
            dataTable.addRows(JSON.parse(arraydata));
```

Problem:

we could not create a line chart according to net income that is second parameter in array ex '44656252' and var names=["Total All Banks","Total All Banks","Total Domestic Banks","Total Domestic Banks","B2B Bank","B2B Bank","Bank of Montreal","Bank of Montreal","The Bank of Nova Scotia","The Bank of Nova Scotia"]

and error is 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number'

Comment: @Epodax we could not create a line chart according to net income  that is second parameter in array ex  '44656252' and var names=["Total All Banks","Total All Banks","Total Domestic Banks","Total Domestic Banks","B2B Bank","B2B Bank","Bank of Montreal","Bank of Montreal","The Bank of Nova Scotia","The Bank of Nova Scotia"]

Comment: Include the problem in your question :) remember to include any errors generated when it's going wrong

Comment: @Epodax error is that Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: Yes, but Edit your question and include those details in there, it makes it easier to read and you avoid people not seeing those details because they don't read the comments.